# If a function calls another contract function that throws, will the initial function throw as well?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

If I call a function in another contract that doesn't return a boolean, but has throw() invariant checks, is it safe to assume the function finished properly if the transaction isn't reverted? 
I ask in the case of a token transfer being called by another contract, since there is no way to know within the contract if the token contract was a success. (ERC-20)

Assume the rest of SampleToken is filled out according to ERC-20 standards.......

```
contract SampleToken {

  /* Send coins */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
  }

}

contract LockContract { 

  function lockTokens(uint256 _period, uint256 _amount)
  external
  returns (bool) { 
    require (sampleToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, _amount));    // Tokens are now transfered into this contract
    return true;
}

  function unlockTokens(uint256 _amountLocked) 
  external
  returns (bool) {
    sampleToken.transfer(msg.sender, _amountLocked);     // This doesn't return boolean, but will throw if error
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you put some piece of code? so that It becomes more clear what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Save the old balance in a variable after transfer has been completed then return a tuple with the old balance and new balance.

```
old_balance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
//transfer here.
return (old_bal,balanceOf[msg.sender]);
```

This give you the proof that transfer happened.

Or

simply check your new balance.

Comment: I'm worried that the user may transfer the tokens to mimic a similar balance change. Also I don't think the contract could know whether any new balance may have come from a different user. (unless a listener notifies it of a Transfer() event being triggered, which I'd like to avoid)